# MembershipProvider Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

In my mvc 4 web application I have a custom membershipprovider used for authorization. But I do not allow authorization for logged in users as well. I need to know what would be the reason. I have implemented only the ValidateUser method. Do I need to implement any other overridden methods? Please help.

If you need any other information, could you please comment below, I can give it.

Here is my membershipProvider class

```
using ABC.DTS.DAO;
using ABC.DTS.DAO.DB;
using ABC.DTS.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

    namespace ABC.DTS.Providers
    {

        public class DTSMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
        {
            public override string ApplicationName
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
                set
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
            {
                try
                {
                    MemberHandler memberHandler = new MemberHandler();
                    LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("DTSMembershipProvider, ValidateUser, Entry, , EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);

                    LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("DTSMembershipProvider, ValidateUser-databaseOpen, Entry, , EmailAddress = " + username);
                    Member user = memberHandler.GetMemberByEmail(username);

                    if (user == null)
                    {

                        LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("error").Debug("DTSMembershipProvider, ValidateUser, Error, Invalid Email Address, EmailAddress = " + username + " Password = " + password);
                        return false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        if (user.Password == password && user != null)
                        {
                            LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("DTSMembershipProvider, ValidateUser, OK, Successful Login, EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);
                            return true;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("DTSMembershipProvider, ValidateUser, Error, Password Error, EmailAddress = " + username + " Password = " + password);
                            LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("error").Debug("DTSMembershipProvider, ValidateUser, Error, Password Error, EmailAddress = " + username + " Password = " + password);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                }

                catch (DAOException de)
                {
                    LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("DTSMembershipProvider, ValidateUser, Error, " + de.Message + ", EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);
                    LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("error").Debug("DTSMembershipProvider, ValidateUser, Error, " + de.Message + ", EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);
                    throw de;
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("DTSMembershipProvider, ValidateUser, Error, " + e.Message + ", EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);
                    LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("error").Debug("DTSMembershipProvider, ValidateUser, Error, " + e.Message + ", EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);
                    throw new DAOException(2002,"Internal Error",e);
                }
            }

            public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override bool EnablePasswordReset
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Also this is my controller class

```
using ABC.DTS.DAO;
using ABC.DTS.Login;
using ABC.DTS.Models;
using ABC.DTS.Providers;
using ABC.DTS.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ABC.DTS.Controllers
{
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Authentication/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Login(string username, string password, int loginMode)
        {
            GenericModel genericmodel;
            try
            {
                LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("AuthenticationController, Login, Entry, , EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);

                ILoginHandler loginHandler;
                LoginHandlerFactory loginHandlerFactory = new LoginHandlerFactory();

                loginHandler = loginHandlerFactory.GetLoginHandler(loginMode);

                if (loginHandler.Login(username, password))
                {
                    LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("AuthenticationController, Login, OK, Successful Login, EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);
                    genericmodel = new GenericModel(0000, "Successfully logged in");
                    return Json(genericmodel);
                }
                else
                {
                    LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("AuthenticationController, Login, Error, Password Error, EmailAddress = " + username + " Password = " + password);
                    LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("error").Debug("AuthenticationController, Login, Error, Password Error, EmailAddress = " + username + " Password = " + password);
                    genericmodel = new GenericModel(1001, "Invalid username or password");
                    return Json(genericmodel);
                }
            }
            catch (DAOException de)
            {
                LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("AuthenticationController, Login, Error, " + de.Message + ", EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);
                LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("error").Debug("AuthenticationController, Login, Error, " + de.Message + ", EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);
                genericmodel = new GenericModel(de.Code, de.Message);
                return Json(genericmodel);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("event").Debug("AuthenticationController, Login, Error, " + e.Message + ", EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);
                LogFileManager.Instance.GetLogger("error").Debug("AuthenticationController, Login, Error, " + e.Message + ", EmailAddress = " + username + "Password = " + password);
                genericmodel = new GenericModel(2002, "Internal Error");
                return Json(genericmodel);
            }
        }

        public ActionResult CheckServer()
        {
            GenericModel _genericModel = new GenericModel(3000, "Server is Live");
            return Json(_genericModel);
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult IsAuthorized()
        {
            GenericModel _genericModel = new GenericModel(0000, "Authorized");
            return Json(_genericModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically we'd need to see your code to help figure out why it's not working...

Comment: I added Files. Please refer

Answer (score 1):

You need to override minimum following two methods -

- **ValidateUser** - it is required to validate.
- **GetUser** - it is called in order to create **IPrincipal** object ever times a request is make to server.

### Custom Membership Provider

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{    
   public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
   {            
   }

   public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
   {           
   }
}
```

### Custom Role Provider

If you need **Authorization** after logging-in, you also need to implement role provider.

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
   public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
   {
   }

   public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
   {
   } 
}
```

Comment: If I give authorization for all logged in users, still do I need role provider?

Comment: If you do not care what role user is in, you do not need role provider.

Comment: But in my case, it doesn't let any user to access the controllers with [Authorozed] tag. I will put my membershipProvider to the question.

Comment: **[Authorized]** is fine. However, ensure that you do not use **[Authorize(Roles = "xxx")]**

Comment: I added relavant files. See the IsAuthorized method in AuthenricatinController. Thanks

Comment: It should work. If it doesn't work, please create a new question with the exception you received.